# Writing Common Table Expressions in SQL (Snowflake)

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, common-table-expression

Just learning how to use common table expressions, I wish I was writing like this from the gate.

I've converted all of my queries in my database to a CTE format using `WITH ... AS` but this one and I am struggling .

So there are two tables:

**Table 1. customers**

- customer_id: unique id for each customer
- full_name: customer full name

**Table 2. subscriptions**

- subscription_id: unique id for subscription
- customer_id: id for customer who subscribed to subscription
- title: name of subscription

The following query is used to return how many subscriptions each of your customers has:

```
SELECT c.customer_id, c.full_name,
(
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM subscriptions s
WHERE s.customer_id = c.customer_id
GROUP BY s.customer_id
) subscriptions_count
FROM customers c
```

How can I rewrite this as a Common Table Expression?

Comment: You cannot.  It is a correlated subquery.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, okay hmmm, would it be possible to tackle the question entirely different to answer the same question (using a CTE)?

Comment: . . Neither a CTE nor a subquery is really needed for what this query is doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to use `CTE` here is one way. You can rewrite it to use `left join` if you wish to show customers with no counts

```
with cte as

(select customer_id, count(*) as counts
from subscriptions
group by customer_id) 

select c.customer_id, c.full_name, s.counts
from customers c
join cte s on s.customer_id=c.customer_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure. You can calculate the aggregate first, then join with `customers`:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT customer_id
         , COUNT(*) AS n
      FROM subscriptions
     GROUP BY customer_id
     )
SELECT c.*
     , COALESCE(cte.n, 0) AS n
  FROM      customers AS c
  LEFT JOIN cte
    ON c.customer_id = cte.customer_id
;
```